# OutOfMemory exception (not sure) android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have problem with my app. App use SQLite. I tried evrything, and it is still crashing.

There is error logs:

```
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): Process: com.example.angielski, PID: 1621
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.angielski/com.example.angielski.BaseList}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at com.example.angielski.BaseList.onCreate(BaseList.java:33)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     ... 11 more
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     ... 24 more
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
08-16 18:04:55.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):     ... 27 more
```

If you need something more of code, just say. I suck...

Help me!

Thanks in advance !

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Go to line #71 of your xml file. What do you have in this line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar error one time. On line #71 do you have a definition of Button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
    android:onClick="menu" />
```

I offer you some solutions to your problem:

1. Override **onLowMemory** method on your Activities to free some resources from memory.
2. Use more [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), [SoftReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) and [WeakHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/WeakHashMap.html),  to avoid strong references, that will be used by the garbage collector to free memory.
3. Use [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) and [inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) options on [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) to decode bitmaps, as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).
4. In my particular problem, I decided to reduce the size of the image to use.
5. Set **android:largeHeap = "true"** on Manifest as describe [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).

Comment: This is not a valid solution. Something goes wrong with memory allocation and freeing resources.
This does not fix the problem, just makes it takes a lot more effort to appear.

Comment: @Jitsu, this fix the problem to Pawel, when you post a solution let me know.

Comment: dont set the **android:largeHeap="true"**. That should be the last option

Comment: To avoid future confusion I will put them in order of priority, thanks @eldjon.

Answer (score 1):

By increasing the heap size you do not solve the bad memory usage in you program. Working with bitmap is a little tricky and you should be very careful about them. Google developer site has a [complete section](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) about working with bitmap which I suggest you should read.