# Out of memory error in BitmapFactory

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

Today I got my app crashed, Out of memory error.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>   in android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset

I only used Bitmap Factory to make a backgroud to my action bar

The code:

```
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.actionbar)); 
         background.setTileModeX(android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); 
         actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

This error doesn't happend on activity start, it happens after changing in activites a lot.

Can someone show me how to fix this

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

Here is the error message in developer console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:646)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:375)
at com.packagename.pp.Activitytwo.disableAnswer(Activitytwo.java:435)
at com.packagename.pp.Activitytwo.submitAnswer(Activitytwo.java:230)
... 14 more
```

Comment: I posted the solution to this problem [here][1].


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344518/outofmemory-exception-not-sure-android/25344553#25344553

Comment: This may suggest you have a memory leak somewhere in your code, ie. you're not freeing the previously allocated bitmap, and something still holds the reference to it.

Comment: @Joseph I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: @Jitsu yes, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a memory leak on your code. Consider the use of [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), [WeakHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) or [SoftReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) to avoid strong references. Free unused resources and variables on onLowMemory method of activities.

Also you can use the option [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) to decode the bitmap as show the examples [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

I posted the some hints to solve this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344518/outofmemory-exception-not-sure-android/25344553#25344553).

Answer (score 0):

first try commenting this code and see if that alone is the issue. It could be something else that might be using up the memory.